# Failing to insert binary stream into a BLOB in hsqldb?

Tags: hsqldb

I have the following hsqldb schema (as reported by SQLWorkbench):

```
DROP TABLE TEST CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
   NAME      VARCHAR(256),
   METADATA  VARCHAR(2048),
   DATA      BLOB
);

GRANT TRIGGER, INSERT, REFERENCES, DELETE, SELECT, UPDATE ON TEST TO DBA;
```

Next, I am trying to insert a file into the DATA field using the following prepared statement:

```
MERGE INTO test  USING (VALUES ?, ?, ?) I (name, metadata, data)  ON (test.name=I.name)  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET test.data = I.data, test.metadata = I.metadata  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (name, metadata, data) VALUES (I.name, I.metadata, I.data)
```

Here is the code:

```
String name = ...;
String metadata = ...;
InputStream data = ...;
JDBCDataSource ds = new JDBCDataSource();
ds.setDatabase("jdbc:hsqldb:file:c:/tmp/file.db");
ds.setUser("sa");
ds.setPassword("");
PreparedStatement set = ds.getConnection().prepareStatement(m_setSql);
set.setString(1, name);
set.setString(2, metadata);
set.setBinaryStream(3, data);
set.executeUpdate();
```

The setBinaryStream fails, because the parameter type is deemed to be `VARCHAR`, rather than `BLOB`. Indeed, the function `org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setBinStream` has the following statement:

```
    if (parameterTypes[parameterIndex - 1].typeCode == Types.SQL_BLOB) {
        setBlobParameter(parameterIndex, x, length);

        return;
    }
```

For the `parameterIndex` 3 it should enter the if-statement and invoke the `setBlobParameter`. But, for some reason, `typeCode` returns 12, which corresponds to `VARCHAR`, the if-statement is skipped and in the end an `org.hsqldb.HsqlException` is raised with the message of **incompatible data type in conversion**.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types of the parameter values in the MERGE statement are unknown and default to VARCHAR. You need to cast the BLOB parameter to BLOB.

```
MERGE INTO test  USING (VALUES ?, ?, CAST(? AS BLOB)) I (name, metadata, data)  
ON (test.name=I.name)  
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET test.data = I.data, test.metadata = I.metadata
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (name, metadata, data) VALUES (I.name, I.metadata, I.data)
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it knew to map the names of the fields to the definitions of the respective fields in the schema.